# Magento 2 custom shipping method hide/show on basis of city

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2, I want to show/hide custom shipping method like delivery in 2 hours radio button if customer fills particular city on checkout page.if he is from that city will show "2 hour delivery option" if not will hide it.
Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use write js in template file like that:

\Namespace\Module\view\frontend\templates\XXX\view\abc.phtml

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[
require(
        ['jquery', 'namespace/module'],
        function ($, xyz) {
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>';
            $(document).ready(xyz.chkCity(ajaxurl));
        });
// ]]>
</script>
```

and keep your js at:
 \Namespace\Module\view\frontend\web\js\abc.js

```
define([
'jquery'
],
    function ($, xyz) {
        return {
            chkCity: function (ajaxurl) {
                $('#city').on('blur', function (e) {
                        //you logic here
                });
            }

        };

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is for shipping method and place order button comes after we select shipping method I want to show or hide shipping option on checkout page only before placing order

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this will not work because on checkout page I am not able to get ID of city field because it changes everytime and along with that I wont be able to add div on onepage.html